# How to invoke method on one @Stateless bean from second @Stateless bean in another package

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, ejb

my problem is similar to this: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903907/how-to-invoke-method-on-one-stateless-bean-from-another-stateless-bean) but i need to invoke method on one @Stateless bean from second @Stateless bean in another package. I tried do it like this:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean1 implements IStatelessBean1{
@EJB
    private packagename.StatelessBeanw pr;
```

after this i get error:

> javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

StatelessBean1 is into defaut package and StatelessBean2 is into package with name. When i get these two int same package all works fine by using:

```
StatelessBean1 pr = new StatelessBean1();
```

Ineed to make it into that kind of 2 different packages

Could someone told how it should look like or where is my mistake?

I tested some more and it look like that even if they are into same package it makes error.

```
@Stateless
    public class StatelessBean1 implements IStatelessBean1{
    @EJB
        private StatelessBeanw pr;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you can use  mappedName construct.

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html#mappedName()) could help you.

Comment: I looked at this link but dunno how it could help me

Comment: @Michal, for example they called remotely the bean in this question with mappedNmame =  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209774/hello-world-with-remote-stateless-session-bean

Answer (score 0):

Thx for hel i guess u have right but in this case answer to my question was easy.
It should be:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean1 implements IStatelessBean1{
@EJB
    private packagename.StatelessBeanwInterface pr;
```

I should give name of interface for my StatelessBeanw file not to StatelessBeanw.
Case closed.